# Error when using the same string in different tests

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, automation

I have the following scenario:
I perform several tests (@Test) and tests in Cucumber, in Selenium Webdriver, Java.

The tests are going well. **However**, I want to leave a string stored in one @Test (public void) in another @Test (public void). I cannot.

Could anyone help?

**First test:**

```
@Test
public void testDocuments() {
     OneClass oneClass = new OneClass();
     oneClass.one();
     oneClass.two();
}
```

**Second test:**

```
@Test
public void testDocuments() {
     OneClass oneClass = new OneClass();
     oneClass.one();
     oneClass.two();
}
```

Method one

```
public String one() {
        if (this.cnpj == null) {
            this.cnpj = add.cnpj(false);
        } else {
        }
        return this.cnpj;
    }
```

Both tests I want you to use the same generated string !!!!

I look forward and thanks in advance!

Comment: @marc
Remember me? lol
Now the problem is to keep the string in different tests
Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need `this.cnpj` value to be available within the second test?
Each time you do `new OneClass()` , it creates a **new** instance of it.

So you can do one of the following:

- Use **singleton** instance of `OneClass`
- Make `cnpj` a `static` field within `OneClass`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your method one() does, but assuming you want to use the same value for two different tests, why not just do this:

```
OneClass oneClass = new OneClass();
String yourGeneratedString = oneClass.one();  

// First test

@Test
public void testDocuments() {
     yourFunction(yourGeneratedString);
}

// Second test

@Test
public void testDocuments2() {
     yourOtherFunction(yourGeneratedString);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Michael S !!!
The error has been resolved !!!

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you want to share data from one test to second one. If you user testNG then you can do it this way.

```
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void testOne(ITestContext context){
    context.setAttribute("myKey", "myValue");
  }

  @Test
  public void testTwo(ITestContext context){
    String valueFromTestOne = (String) context.getAttribute("myKey");
    System.out.println("My key = " + valueFromTestOne);
  }
}
```

[image]